# Run shell script from python with PIPE and cat files with name as variable

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, pipe

I tried to run shell script from Python using subprocess library such as:

1.

```
call(f'cat {file}.pvar {output_file}.pvar | sort | uniq -u >> {removed_snp_file}', shell=True)
```

with error:

`/bin/sh: 1: cannot open _io.TextIOWrapper: No such file`

or

2.

```
with open(removed_snp_file, 'a', encoding="utf-8") as myoutfile: 
    p1 = Popen(["cat", f'{file}.pvar', f'{output_file}.pvar'], stdout=PIPE)
    p2 = Popen(["sort"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
    p3 = Popen(["uniq", "-u"], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=myoutfile)
    p3.communicate()
```

with error

`cat: '<_io.TextIOWrapper name='\''/home/panacota/Desktop/qc_pipeline/data/quality_control/HapMap_3_r3_1_quality_control_report.csv'\'' mode='\''a'\'' encoding='\''ANSI_X3.4-1968'\''>.pvar': No such file or directory`

,where file, output_file, removed_snp_file are str variables. How I should change my code to make it work?

Comment: Check your output_fil and removed_snp_file variables. Appears that they are not file names.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, before this script line I open file as `with open(report_file, 'a') as file:` and re-write the variable.